A simple question about probability of multiple trials
Say the probability that player A wins round 1 of a game is 1/10, player B is 2/10,and player C is 3/10.
If no player wins in a round, it simply moves on to the next round with the same probabilities.
The game keeps going until a player wins.
My question is, if we were to calculate the probability that Player A wins the whole game, would it be 1/10? Or would it be something else?
I can't seem to wrap my head around what the probability would be of Player A winning the whole game, and why that would be.
Shouldn't the probability be the same regardless of how many rounds there are, since the probabilities reset every round? But this doesn't seem intuitive to me.
Would appreciate any insight regarding this, thanks!

I'll look into two approaches. Let $A_i$ be the event that player $A$ wins in round $i$, similarly for $B_i$ and $C_i$. Let $N_i$ be the probability that nobody wins in round $i$.
Since after the first game is played, you realize that you are in the identical situation that you were in before, so the probability of $A$ winning, given that the first round failed, is still the same. We can write this in the form of
$$\mathbb{P}(A)=\mathbb{P}(A_1)+\mathbb{P}(N_1)\mathbb{P}(A)$$
We can sum these two as they are disjoint events, $A$ wins in round $1$ and $A$ wins after round $1$. After plugging in the values we have $$\mathbb{P}(A)=\frac{1}{10}+\frac{4}{10}\mathbb{P}(A)\Rightarrow \mathbb{P}(A)=\frac{1}{6}.$$
Similarly, you get $\mathbb{P}(B)=\frac{2}{6}$ and $\mathbb{P}(C)=\frac{3}{6}$.
In a different way, these are disjoint events, the probability that $A$ wins in general is $$\sum^{\infty}_{i=1}A_i=\sum^{\infty}_{i=1}\frac{1}{10}\left(\frac{4}{10}\right)^n=\frac{1}{6}.$$
For intuition, simplify to the case that you are playing against an adversary called Bob. Bob has a coin that comes up heads with probability $\frac{1}{10}$, and tails otherwise. But with probability $\frac{1}{2}$, Bob fails to catch the coin and you flip again. Now you wouldn't feel betting on heads $\$10$ against Bobs $\$10$ on tails, but you perhaps would feel more comfortable betting $\$1$ (try working out what a good bet might be). Now imagine Bob stops failing to catch the coin, your preference for the game shouldn't change much, as it is your relative advantages that factor into your bet. Notice that in the original problem, the ratio between the probabilities is still the same.
Hope this helps.
